# How to "extend" classes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to create two typeclasses, `A` and `B`, where `A` is a superclass of `B`. The functions defined in `B` are sufficient to implement those in `A`. Then, if I have a function with the constraint `fun :: (A thing) => ...` an instance of `B` for, say, `Int`, I'd like to be able to pass an `Int` to `fun` without creating a duplicate instance `A` for `Int`.

For example, let's say I have a type class which can check if value is "even". Then, I have another type class which can check if a value is divisible by some number. The second type class is powerful enough to implement the functions in the first, and any function which only requires "even-checking" capabilities should be able to accept an argument which has "divisible-by" abilities.

Here's what I think it would look like:

```hs
class IsEven a where
  isEven :: a -> Bool

class (IsEven a) => DivisibleBy a where
  divisibleBy :: a -> Int -> Bool
  isEven :: a -> Bool
  isEven a = divisibleBy a 2

printIsEven :: (IsEven a) => a -> IO ()
printIsEven a = putStrLn (show (IsEven.isEven a))

instance IsEven Int  -- I need to do this or I cannot create a DivisibleBy instance
instance DivisibleBy Int where
  divisibleBy a i = a `mod` i == 0

myint :: Int
myint = 2

main :: IO ()
main = printIsEven myint
```

However, at compile time this produces the warning:

```
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Foo.hs, Foo.o )

Foo.hs:11:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        ‘IsEven.isEven’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘IsEven Int’
   |
11 | instance IsEven Int
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^
Linking Foo ...
```

and at runtime, the program fails:

```
Foo: Foo.hs:11:10-19: No instance nor default method for class operation isEven
```

How can I achieve this subtyping effect without duplicating logic into an `instance IsEven`?

Comment: There is no reason for `DivisibleBy` to be a subclass of `IsEven`. The *opposite* relation is reasonable, as is making the two classes independent. Just because using `divisibleBy` is *one* way to define `isEven` doesn't mean an `IsEven` instance should be *required*.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, the closest you can get in standard Haskell is

```
instance IsEven Int where
  isEven n = n `divisibleBy` 2

instance DivisibleBy Int where
  divisibleBy a i = a `mod` i == 0
```

You don't have to duplicate the logic (indeed, you can implement `isEven` in terms of `divisibleBy`), but you still need to provide an explicit definition.

You would have to repeat this pattern for every type you want to make an instance of `DivisibleBy`.

Using the [`DefaultSignatures` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures) you can also do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class IsEven a where
  isEven :: a -> Bool
  default isEven :: (DivisibleBy a) => a -> Bool
  isEven n = n `divisibleBy` 2

class (IsEven a) => DivisibleBy a where
  divisibleBy :: a -> Int -> Bool

instance IsEven Int
instance DivisibleBy Int where
  divisibleBy a i = a `mod` i == 0
```

This moves the default implementation to the class itself. Now you can indeed just say `instance IsEven Int` without providing an instance body. The disadvantage is that now `IsEven` has to know about `DivisibleBy`, and you can only provide one `default` implementation.

Comment: It might be worth it to explicitly note that the `liftM` idiom (in this case, defining `isEvenDivisible :: DivisibleBy a => a -> Bool` for the sake of writing boilerplate `IsEven` instances) might make the Haskell 98 solution slightly more comfortable. (Ultimately, I guess, it is a matter of how many extra names is one willing to tolerate, versus how often one can stand rewriting the full boilerplate implementation.)

Answer (score 7):

You can't redefine a method in a new class and have it affect the one in the old class. If you want methods to work like this, the parent class has to reference the child class.

You need [the `DefaultSignatures` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DefaultSignatures) to make this work. Turn it on and then change your classes to this:

```
class IsEven a where
  isEven :: a -> Bool
  default isEven :: DivisibleBy a => a -> Bool
  isEven a = divisibleBy a 2

class IsEven a => DivisibleBy a where
  divisibleBy :: a -> Int -> Bool
```

Comment: hm, but what if then there is some other type class which also has enough functionality to implement `isEven`? It seems like doing it this way requires the superclass to "know about" its subclass. In Scala, for example, you can subclass any typeclass and provide implementations for the superclasses methods. Eg, `Applicative` can implement `Functor`'s `map` using `ap`: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Applicative.scala#L48 Is there a way to achieve something similar in Haskell? In Scala, if there is an `Applicative` in scope, you get a `Functor` for free.

Comment: @DavidAbrahams I don't believe that Haskell currently has any equivalent to that functionality.

Answer (score 5):

With GHC 8.6 and above, this can also be achieved through [`DerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-via):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

-- Class definitions:

class IsEven a where
  isEven :: a -> Bool

-- Note that we don't need to have IsEven as a superclass.
class DivisibleBy a where
  divisibleBy :: a -> Int -> Bool


-- Boilerplate that only needs to be written once:

-- Boilerplate DivisibleBy instance generated with GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving.
newtype WrappedDivisibleBy a = WrapDivisibleBy { unwrapDivisibleBy :: a }
  deriving DivisibleBy

instance DivisibleBy a => IsEven (WrappedDivisibleBy a) where
  isEven n = n `divisibleBy` 2 


-- Instance example:

instance DivisibleBy Int where
  divisibleBy a i = a `mod` i == 0

-- Boilerplate IsEven instance generated with DerivingVia 
-- (and StandaloneDeriving, as we aren't defining Int here).
deriving via (WrappedDivisibleBy Int) instance IsEven Int
```

`DerivingVia` is not always an option (in the case of classes like `Traversable`, which have an extra type constructor wrapping things in the type signature, it clashes with the role system); when it works, though, it is very neat.

Comment: Ah this is neat! I actually don't think we need `DivisibleBy` to extend `isEven` in this case, correct? (It compiles without it)

Comment: @DavidAbrahams We don't, indeed. I have updated the answer to reflect that. (While here I'm primarily dealing with the typeclass mechanics, [chepner does have a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911322/how-to-extend-classes-in-haskell/56913699?noredirect=1#comment100372810_56911322) about this specific example, so dropping the relationship looks like a net gain as far as this answer is concerned.)

Comment: I always wanted `unsafe via` to bypass the role system, it would use [`unsafeCoerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) instead of [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce)

Comment: @Iceland_jack Tangential question: will the `QuantifiedConstraints` approach discussed [in this ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14070) allow deriving `Traversable` and `Distributive`? Though I might well be reading the situation wrongly, it looks like that would demand coercing under an arbitrary functor that the instance implementer has no control over.

Comment: Not as smoothly as `join`, requires big changes but I think it is the best path forward, the `forall f a b. Applicative f =>` quantification appears in the type of `traverse @t @f @a..`, we can only work with `t`. Either strengthen `Applicative f` with `Representational1` or decree all `Functor`s be representational in their first arg by making `class Representational1 f => Functor f` a superclass. Ryan explains better: [**`QuantifiedConstraints` and the trouble with `Traversable`**](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2018/06/22/quantifiedconstraints-and-the-trouble-with-traversable/).